# How to select items from dropdown list by selenium

Tags: java, selenium

In my testing UI, I need to automate a case as this in selenium java.

```
1. To click an icon, so that the pop-up list will be shown up, 
2. then to select an item from the pop-up list.
```

But I am clueless how this can be done from following html code. This is the code after the icon has been clicked.

```
<ul class="pull-right header-helpers">
   <li class="helpers-user hide-min-width"> ... </li>
   <li class="helpers-help hide-min-width"> ... </li>
   <li class="dropdown user-dropdown open"> 
       <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          <div>...</div>
       </div>
       <div class="dropdown-backdrop"></div>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                <a action = "Option-A"/>
            </li>
            <li class="driver" role="separator"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                <a action = "Option-B"/>
            </li>
            <li class="driver" role="separator"></li>
       </ul>
</ul>
```

If icon hasn't been clicked, line 4 would be as this:

```
<li class="dropdown user-dropdown">
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: which language your using ? java?

Comment: yes. it is in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the dropdown value you want to select and click it. This is to select the option A in the dropdown. You can replace option value with params and handle dynamically to select required option.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
 WebElement dropdown= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".dropdown-menu a[action='Option-A']")));
 dropdown.click();
```

Comment: I never done this before.  But where does the above code make the first click ? It will not shown until the pops-up happens, right ? Using your code, during the automation running, while it was waiting, if I manually click the icon to have it pop up, then I see item is being automated picked.

Comment: Yes. before this code. Click the appropriate element using findelement and click method.

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking the tick mark next to the answer